# Insert similar rows in database

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a next structure:

```
+---------+----------+-------+
| user_id | group_id | onoff |
+---------+----------+-------+
|       1 |        3 |     1 |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

Here is many users and many groups. Currently max group is 18.
How can I insert `group_id=19` with `onoff=1` for all users in the table? (I mean insert in one query)

Comment: you want to do multiple inserts in one query? INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

Comment: Is your user_id auto increment, clear you question, do you want to add new rows with group_id 19 for all the user or update current rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a subselect clause to insert your values ([MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)).

```
INSERT INTO yourTable
  ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id, 19, 1 FROM yourTable )
```

Example can be seen at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f408/1/0).

Comment: Testing on live now. Wait a sec ;)